# Raster Polygon Overlay Analysys

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, overlay, grids-graticules

I have a fishnet polygon feature class and a land cover (40 categories) raster. Both cover a large area.

I seek to:

a) calculate the area of each land cover type category (40) inside of each Grid from the fishnet,

b) Overlay those two datasets in order to have just 1 dataset. What´s the best option to have just a layer showing the Land cover type inside of each Grid?
[image]

c) Clip the Grid for just work with the areas of the grid that match the land cover map. Yet I do not want an exact clipped grid but instead that the fishnet grid from the raster boundaries would not get clipped, thus, maintaining the full grid configuration in overlaid areas.
[image]

What is the best approach to reach the goals for a), b) and c)?
Additionally, is it possible to do it without converting the raster to polygon or polygon to raster?

Comment: Arcgis is the software

Comment: Tabulate areas and join result to net.